# find maxima and minima of $ y=\frac{\ln^2x}{x}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

$$ y=\frac{\ln^2x}{x}$$

finally I got

$t = 0$ and $t = -2$ after $\ln x = t$

but I am not sure if it is correct cause both of them do not exist by default

Comment: What is $\ln^2x$? Is that $(\ln x)^2$ or $\ln(\ln(x))\,$?

Comment: Assuming this is $y=(\ln x)^2 / x$ for $x\gt 0$, there is a global minimum and a local maximum

Comment: To differentiate your function, use the chain rule on the numerator and then use the quotient rule.

Comment: They do exist;$\ln(0),\ln(-2)$ do not exist but $\ln x=0\implies x=1$ and $\ln x=-2\implies x=e^{-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

we have:
$$
y'=\frac{2\ln x-\ln^2 x}{x^2}
$$
so $y'=0$ for:
$$
\ln x=0 \quad \mbox{or} \quad \ln x=2
$$

can you solve ?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln^2(x)}{x^2}$ then $f'(x)=\frac{\ln x(\ln x-2)}{x^2}$. So $\ln x=0$, which means $x=1$, or $\ln x=2$, which means $x=e^2$.

I'll let you check the second derivative to know which one is a maximum and which one is a minimum.